# Как установить Django Blog Zinnia?

Tags: установка, ubuntu, postgresql, django

Подскажите, как мне установить Django Blog Zinnia на Ubuntu +  PostgreSQL.

Желательно опишите поэтапно...

Comment: Блин да ответьте хоть на один мой вопрос, или я их не коректно задаю ?

Comment: Вы задали всего один. ХэшКод - это форум, посвященный программированию и с вопросами установки ПО мало перекликается.

Answer (score 3):

Вот отличное описание: [blog zinnia](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/getting-started/install.html)

Comment: Что мне нужно делать после этих действий?


    $ git clone git://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia.git

    $ cd django-blog-zinnia

    $ python setup.py install

Comment: @maxwelhelp настраивать среду. В описании ниже написано о том, что нужно прописать в секцию INSTALLED_APPS, чтобы добавить zinnia в свой проект. Ну и дальше по шагам.